# SQL Server PK violation while inserting from two different access forms

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have SQL Server DB connected to Access 2007 Form 
i use Function in SQL to create the DB ID automatically while executing inserting procedure  to insert new record as below 
but, when i try to insert a lot of records at the same time from two different PC through the Access "Not Using the Same Access File there is one file only for each PC"
i get Error Message said that i can`t insert the record due to violation in SQL Primary key "try to insert two record with same ID" 
but, if i try to use it through one PC only it works fine ...... so, please advise :

Function Code :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Attachment_MaxID] ()
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
declare @Result int 
SELECT @Result = max(Attachament_ID) +1 from [dbo].[TBL_Attachment]
RETURN @Result;
end
```

Inserting Procedure code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Justification_Insert]
    (
      @Justification_Cisco INT ,
      @Justification_Date_Of_Case DATETIME ,
      @Justification_AgentShift DATETIME ,
      @Justification_From DATETIME ,
      @Justification_To DATETIME ,
      @Justification_OT_Duration DATETIME ,
      @Justification_Justification VARCHAR(60) ,
      @Justification_Description VARCHAR(255) ,
      @Justification_Creator VARCHAR(80) ,
      @Justification_Approved_By VARCHAR(80) ,
      @Justification_Type VARCHAR(40) ,
      @Justification_Group_ID INT ,
      @Attachament_File_Ext NVARCHAR(10) ,
      @Attachament_Ori_Path NVARCHAR(255) ,
      @Attachament_New_Path NVARCHAR(255)
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Justification_MaxID INT = NULL ,
            @Justification_ID INT   = NULL ,
            @Attachment_MaxID INT = NULL ,
            @Attachment_ID INT  = NULL


        SELECT  @Justification_ID = [JTA].[dbo].[FN_Justification_MaxID]()
        SELECT  @Attachment_ID = [JTA].[dbo].[FN_Attachment_MaxID]()

        SET NOCOUNT ON;


        INSERT  INTO [dbo].[TBL_Justification]
                ( Justification_ID ,
                  Justification_Cisco ,
                  Justification_Date_Of_Case ,
                  Justification_AgentShift ,
                  Justification_From ,
                  Justification_To ,
                  Justification_OT_Duration ,
                  Justification_Justification ,
                  Justification_Description ,
                  Justification_Creator ,
                  Justification_Approved_By ,
                  Justification_Type ,
                  Justification_Group_ID ,
                  Justification_DT
                )
        VALUES  ( @Justification_ID ,
                  @Justification_Cisco ,
                  @Justification_Date_Of_Case ,
                  @Justification_AgentShift ,
                  @Justification_From ,
                  @Justification_To ,
                  @Justification_OT_Duration ,
                  @Justification_Justification ,
                  @Justification_Description ,
                  @Justification_Creator ,
                  @Justification_Approved_By ,
                  @Justification_Type ,
                  @Justification_Group_ID ,
                  GETDATE()
                )


        INSERT  INTO TBL_attachment
                ( [Attachament_Justification_ID] ,
                  [Attachament_ID] ,
                  [Attachament_File_Ext] ,
                  [Attachament_Ori_Path] ,
                  [Attachament_New_Path] ,
                  [Attachament_DT]
                )
        VALUES  ( @Justification_ID ,
                  @Attachment_ID ,
                  @Attachament_File_Ext ,
                  @Attachament_Ori_Path ,
                  @Attachament_New_Path ,
                  GETDATE()
                )


    END
```

VBA Code:

```
Dim con As Object
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open _
            "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=YAMANI-PC;UID=mohamed.elyamani;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=JTA"
  con.Execute "exec [SP_Justification_Insert] " & Justification_Cisco & ",'" & Justification_Date_Of_Case & "'" _
  & " ,'" & Justification_AgentShift & "','" & Justification_From & "','" & Justification_To & "' ,'" & Justification_OT_Duration & "'" _
  & " ,'" & Justification_Justification & "','" & Justification_Description & "' ,'" & Justification_Creator & "','" & Justification_Approved_By _
  & "','" & Justification_Type & "' ,'" & Justification_Group_ID & "','" & FileExt & "','" & TempVars!SourceFile & "','" & destinationFile & "'"

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
end sub
```

Comment: So you are getting the key with select max + 1? Never going to work with multiple apps. They are both likely to get the same max, hence the violation. Any reason you couldn't just make the key an identity (autonumber) ?

Comment: You could catch the error and increment again until you don't get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is a concurrency one where you have multiple requests getting the same id back.  The easiest way to solve it is simply to make your PK columns (Justification_ID and Attachment_ID) IDENTITY columns (more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Alternatively you can run in SERIALIZABLE isolation level in your proc with a transaction around your two selects and inserts.  So after your DECLARE block you would have SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; BEGIN TRAN; and then have a COMMIT; before your end.  This would guarantee that you would only get one set of ids per run, but also means that each subsequent call needs to wait on the previous one to finish, which may not be desirable.

Using an IDENTITY column for your PK ids is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: Could you please write the procedure will get the scope identity or how I add it to current procedure

Answer (score 1):

This is the source of your error:

```
SELECT @Result = max(Attachament_ID) +1 from [dbo].[TBL_Attachment]
```

It's entirely possible that two processes get the same `MAX` value, do their inserts and find a conflicting PK. There're two ways you can solve this problem:

1. Use `IDENTITY` for the `Justification_ID` and `Attachment_ID` columns. You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the just-inserted value.
2. If you are on SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can also use `SEQUENCE` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff878091.aspx)) to query for the next value, without fear of another process getting the same value and cause a PK conflict.

Comment: if the above select is wrong could u please correct it for me ?

Comment: my problem for using identity were 1- i use the same ID to insert record in two different tabels so, if i made it automatic i can`t do it for both tabels 2- i want to get each inserted IDs to pass again to the form

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement is fine as it is, just the approach that is prone to concurrency problem. You can get back the inserted ID like this `SET @Justification_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the `INSERT`.

Comment: i did it but i get new problem i have two ID`s and i want to pass both of them to the access form my code just pass the first one i use recordset it just pass the first one how shall i pass both of them:
var= recordset.Fields(0).Value

Comment: Do you always expect 2 IDs back? Or it will vary? If the second case, you need to return a table to Access

Comment: i want two ids for two differnt tabels to return back to the form after inserting

Comment: i want both of them separately in two different variables